# How to measure microvolts of biopotential with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage-measurement, biopotential

I'm new to electronics, so don't judge me harshly. I need to measure the biopotential of a human. I will place special electrodes on the skin, and need to measure the voltage on it. Ordinarily, the voltage is in range of 0.01 - 300 microvolts. I need to measure this voltage and collect it with the help of an Arduino (or maybe another similar microcontroller). How can I go about making this?

Comment: If you add what biopotential you're trying to measure, it will help us understand your frequency requirements, which are key in determining whether your task is easy or difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than give specific circuits, I think I should point you in a few directions.

Google on "eeg amplifier", "ecg amplifier" and "ekg amplifier".

In general, your job will be much easier if you can accept AC-coupled amplifiers - that is, if you don't need to measure DC potentials. You will need total gains in the range of about 10,000 to see your signals, and this is generally best done in several modest stages.

You will need to learn about shielding, and the use of coaxial cable and twisted pairs. Searching for application notes on low-noise techniques will also be helpful, especially anything by Robert Pease and Jim Williams.

Answer (score 0):

A project like this will be very difficult for a beginner to design.  The amplifier noise, gain, stability issues and signal integrity / shielding would be a challenge even for an experienced designer.

There's an open source project "[SHIELD-EKG-EMG](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/open-source-hardware) - Open Source Hardware Electrocardiography electromyography shield" for Arduino that does what I think you're looking for. 
They mention it was used in a project for [Muscle Control](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_7BzUED39A).

[image]